# Finding eigenvalues of the laplacian operator

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

In order to find the engenvalues of the laplacian, this is what I did:

$$\nabla u = -\lambda u, \ (x^2 + y^2 <1)\\u = 0, (x^2 + y^2 =1)$$

In order to solve this problem, I worked with the polar coordinate change of variables:

$$u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)$$

then the problem becomes $$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta} = -\lambda(R(r)\Theta(\theta))$$

which becomes

$$\frac{R''(r)}{R(r)}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{R'(r)}{R(r)}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\Theta''(\theta)}{\Theta(\theta)} = -\lambda$$

Now do

$$\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = -\gamma\implies \Theta'' +\gamma\Theta = 0$$ $$R''+\frac{1}{r}R'+(\lambda-\frac{\gamma}{r^2})R=0$$

The characteristic equation for $\Theta''+ \gamma\Theta = 0$ is $p^2 + \gamma=0$ or $p=\pm\sqrt{-\gamma}$. We have a feasible solution only when $\gamma>0$ (**WHY?**) thus $$\Theta(\theta) = A\cos\sqrt{\gamma}\theta + B\sin\sqrt{\gamma}\theta$$

which implies that $\sqrt{\gamma} = n\in \mathbb{N}$ due to the $2\pi$-periodicity Finally we arrive at $$\Theta(\theta) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}A_0,& n=0\\A_n\cos n\theta + B_n\sin n\theta,& n\in \mathbb{N}\end{cases}$$ for appropriate constants $A_0, A_n, B_n$

Next we solve $\frac{R''(r)}{R(r)}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{R'(r)}{R(r)}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\Theta''(\theta)}{\Theta(\theta)} = -\lambda$ for $0\le r < 1$. We impose that at the origin, $R(0)$ is finite. Also, the Dirichlet Boundary conditions require $R(1)=0$. We know that the Dirichlet-Laplacian eigenvalues are positive, so $\lambda >0$

Now let us use the change of variable: $\rho = \sqrt{\lambda} r$ which results in $R_r = R_{\rho}\frac{d\rho}{dr} = \sqrt{\lambda}R_{\rho}, R_{rr} = \lambda R_{\rho\rho}$

Now the equation can be rewritten as $$R_{\rho\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}R_{\rho} + (1-\frac{n^2}{\rho^2})R=0$$

which is the Bessel Equation which has solution $R(\rho) = J_n(\rho)$ where

$$J_n(\rho) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)^{n+2k}$$

> So for $n$ in general $$u(r,\theta) =
>  R(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\lambda}})\Theta(\theta) =
>  J_n(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\lambda}})(A_n\cos n\theta + B_n\sin n\theta)$$
>
> and for the case $n=0$:
>
> $$u(r,\theta) = R(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\lambda}})\Theta(\theta) =
>  J_0(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\lambda}})(\frac{1}{2}A_0)$$

Is this solution right? It seems kinda different from [this solution](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/LapEig/lecpdf/lecture5.pdf) in the page 5 where it shows the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: You still have to evaluate the condition $J_n(\frac1{\sqrtλ})=0$, which gives discrete values for $λ$ which are the eigenvalues.

Comment: You’re change of variables is not to polar coordinates, that is assuming the form of the solution to be seperable AFTER converting to polar coordinates.

Comment: @LutzL why $1$ in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$? Could you be more specific or write an answer? Thank you so much

Comment: You are right, I was misled by the error in your last formulas. You should have $R(r)=R(\fracρ{\sqrtλ})=J_n(ρ)=J_n(r\sqrtλ)$, so that the boundary condition leads to $J_n(\sqrtλ)=0$. One problem is that you use $R$ for two functions of differently scaled variables, and you mix the scales wrongly in the conclusion of your computation.

Comment: @LutzL do you know the WHY that I updated in my question?

Comment: $Θ$ needs to be $2\pi$-periodic. For $γ<0$ the solution is never periodic, not even bounded, thus no usable solution for the problem exists.

Comment: @LutzL do you know also why he does $\theta''/\theta =-\gamma$?

Comment: Do you mean "why it is constant" or "why the minus sign"? The first because the independent variables are independent, the second because of the foreknowledge that the solution will come from a harmonic oscillator equation.

Comment: Ok, I almost understood everythig, but why $R(r)=R(\fracρ{\sqrtλ})=J_n(ρ)=J_n(r\sqrtλ)$? I can only see $R$ being used for one thing. Can you show where is the problem? Why $J_n(\sqrt{\lambda})$ must be $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct up to the line where you introduce the Bessel functions. There you should have written
$$
R(\fracρ{\sqrtλ})=J_n(ρ)\iff R(r)=J_n(\sqrtλr).
$$
For greater clarity start earlier, when substituting $r$ with $ρ$ do not reuse the same function name for two different functions, write $R(r)=\tilde R(ρ)$ where $ρ=\sqrtλr$, $R_r=\sqrtλ\tilde R_ρ$ etc., so that the Bessel equation is in $\tilde R$ and its derivatives. Then its solution is $\tilde R(ρ)=J_n(ρ).$ With that you get a clean back substitution 
$$R(r)=\tilde R(ρ)=\tilde R(\sqrtλr)=J_n(\sqrtλr).$$

And as $R(1)=0$ we need that $\sqrtλ$ is one of the roots of $J_n$.

Comment: Is $\lambda>0$ in $\nabla u = -\lambda u, \ (x^2 + y^2 <1)$? If so, why it can't be negative?

Comment: Multiply with $u$, integrate, apply Green's theorem to get $$\|∇u\|_{L^2}^2=λ\|u\|_{L^2},$$ which implies that $λ>0$. You should correct the symbols, the Laplace operator is `\Delta`, $\Delta$, while `\nabla`, $\nabla$, is used for the gradient.

Comment: Why $\theta$ must be $2\pi$ periodic?

Comment: Because $Θ$ is a function on a circle. To be continuous on the full circle, you need $Θ(\pi)=Θ(-\pi)$ and thus, in extension from $[-\pi,\pi]$ to $\Bbb R$, $Θ(θ+2\pi)=Θ(θ)$.